# How to use fillwithdottedlines with the number of lines?

Tags: exam

With the exam package, I would like to know how many lines I want to give for an answer. Giving a height relies on the line-height parameter.

Is it possible to say "I want to add 5 dotted lines"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter `\dottedlinefillheight` is defined as a so-called *length*, which means you can use it with a multiplication factor, similar to for example

`\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{example-image}`

When you use `n\dottedlinefillheight` as the argument to `\fillwithdottedlines` then `n` will be the number of lines that is printed.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question
In no more than one paragraph, explain why the earth is round.
\fillwithdottedlines{5\dottedlinefillheight}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]